# coffeescript-react (.cjsx) Support in Webstorm

Tags: coffeescript, syntax-highlighting, webstorm, reactjs

Is there a way to get any kind of syntax highlighting for [.cjsx](https://github.com/jsdf/coffee-react-transform) (jsx in coffeescript) files in WebStorm?

Currently, I'm using a [Sublime plugin](https://github.com/reactjs/sublime-react/), which is great, but I'd prefer to stay in WebStorm if possible.
I understand WebStorm supports TextMate bundles, so that may be a viable option but I couldn't find one for cjsx.

Comment: WebStorm's ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12464

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't look like there's much activity on that issue.

Comment: Well.. 22 votes only (which is pretty good, actually.. but not that much compared to other popular technologies/requests). Priority also also depends on how popular technology is in real world. I may only suggest asking in the ticket about their plans: will proper support make into next major version (v10) .. or maybe they will  provide some support for it in a different way. I'm using none of these (CoffeeScript or React) and have no idea about their current plans, but so far this ticket is not associated/planned with any future release.

Comment: Update: Rus Werner has [posted](http://www.residue.io/2015/01/30/webstorm-cjsx-support/) about his experience hacking up a TextMate bundle that may offer some improvement.    
My experience with it wasn't very good since it mucked up the background color of the text for the theme I use  (Darcula), but some of you may have more success.

Comment: Same here background messed up for my theme

Comment: @burtyish I`ve fixed the background, while in IDE Settings see the box below TextMateBundles - where you can match IDE Color Scheme and TextMate Color Scheme - just put the right ones and reenable the bundle! Thats it!

Comment: **Update:** I've been coding in ES2015 for a while now, gradually converting  my old cjsx files to js using bable.js. I highly recommend it. WebStorm supports babel beautifully, including Emmet and syntax highlighting.

Comment: @burtyish Can you use the "go to definition" (usually Ctrl+]) with cjsx in WebStorm? I don't see to be able to do that. Keep getting "Cannot find declaration to go to".

Comment: @AndyShuXin, that's off topic. But yes, I can.

Comment: @burtyish How did you do it? Or should I ask a separate question?

Answer (score 5):

[Atom, the hackable editor](https://atom.io/), written in coffeescript, has great support for cjsx.   (yes, look at that, another really, really, really large project using coffeescript)

I'm using the community (a really, really large community) supported package cjsx-language https://atom.io/packages/language-cjsx

I've almost broken the $1200 chain of IntelliJ.   Here is a gist of my atom setup and packages: https://gist.github.com/littlebee/34a60734de79f6f78c56

This was saved by this genius little package: https://atom.io/packages/sync-settings.  It wont let you backup to my gist without a key but it might let you restore from it.

Comment: Since asking the question I, too, have found that Atom offers better cjsx support than Sublime and do recommend it.   
However, this answer does not answer the question regarding Webstorm.  

Thanks for sharing your setup anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Use this textmate bundle (meant for webstorm cjsx): https://github.com/ruswerner/cjsx.tmbundle

Comment: This is the only proper answer here

Answer (score 1):

I would advice against using CoffeeScript in WebStorm for large projects (see comments section). If you really need to, then you can always use backticks to tell the CoffeeScript compiler to skip the code within the backticks.

```
render: () ->
    return `<div>Hi</div>`;
```

WebStorm will highlight this just fine if in Settings you select "JSX Harmony" as in the Javascript settings. Now let these `cjsx` files compile in 2 steps: `CoffeeScript` -> `JavaScript with JSX`, then `JavaScript with JSX` -> `JavaScript`. If you're using Webpack, it's as simple as:

```
{include: /\.cjsx$/, loaders: ["coffee-loader", "jsx-loader"]}
```

Comment: `I would advice against using CoffeeScript in general.` You need to justify that or remove it.

Comment: @jcollum Because WebStorm does not primarily support CoffeeScript – so it seems to me. Especially if you compare it to their JavaScript support, it's really not as complete. For example: code reformatting never works 100%. There're always some lines (like nested object definitions) that get distorted.

Comment: Webstorm CoffeeScript support is generally fantastic, including full-stack debugging with single-stepping - all in CoffeeScript.